# React Router generated link is prevented default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I started using react router in my code, but all the links generated by `<Link>` or even `<a>` tag don't work. When I hold the mouse on these links I can see the URL, which is correct, but when I click on them nothing happens. I mean the URL in the browser doesn't change. It seems I used `e.preventDefault`! Since I'm new in using React Router, I guess I missed something.

Here is part of the code (the complete code is really long):

index.js:

```
<Router>
 ...
 <Menu />
 ...
 <Switch>
     <Route path='/smodel/datasource' component={DataSource}/>
 </Switch>
 ...
</Router>
```

menu.js

```
<Link to="/smodel/datasource">New</Link>;
```

I used `withRouter` function in both pages for connect, since I used redux.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to restructure your code like:

```
...
 <Menu />
 ...
<Router>
 <Switch>
     <Route path='/smodel/datasource' component={DataSource}/>
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Having `<Menu />` inside `<Router />` needs to have `<Route />` which isn't the case. You're simply assigning Links so they need to be outside the `<Router />`.

The `<Router />` can have `<Switch />` and `<div />` or any elements and can be nested inside with `<Route />`s.

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. This leads to this error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Comment: Hmm, you're messing with something.

Comment: the structure is fine. `Router` is a context provider which should only be used once, near the top of the app tree. It must have only a single child element so `<React.Fragment>` can be used to wrap multiple child components if necessary.